# How to customise the scrollbar

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, scrollbar

Hi I'm currently working on this website below
http://koogen.net/wp/

id:test
pass:2015

and I have two column where we scroll to see contents.
I have been coding in Mac but I realized that in IE, windows,
scroll bar has this transparent grey track color and design don't look the same with Mac browsers.

[image: scroll bar shown in Mac]
scroll bar shown in Mac

[image: scroll bar shown in Win has grey background and it gets in a way of the logo]
scroll bar shown in Win has grey background and it gets in a way of the logo

How can I customize them 
so that the scroll bar will look the same with Mac's.

Any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your CSS:

```
body {
     scrollbar-base-color: #C0C0C0;
     scrollbar-base-color: #C0C0C0;
     scrollbar-3dlight-color: #C0C0C0;
     scrollbar-highlight-color: #C0C0C0;
     scrollbar-track-color: #EBEBEB;
     scrollbar-arrow-color: black;
     scrollbar-shadow-color: #C0C0C0;
     scrollbar-dark-shadow-color: #C0C0C0;
}
```

**Customise the colors according to your requirements**

Comment: thanks for the fast reply! Unfortunately,, I am still seeing grey scroll bar..(I am using Internet explorer 11)

Comment: @HirohitoYamada Can you please provide a link to the webpage or if not possible, then atleast a jsfiddle of what you have done so far

Comment: I wrote the link for my website at the very first sentence of my question, please take a look at that link! Thank you!

http://koogen.net/wp/
id:test pass:2015

Comment: Check this out: http://forums.asp.net/t/1631637.aspx?scrollbar+style+in+chrome+firefox+safari